# Communicating between XUL and Java

Tags: java, xul

I would like to use a mixture of Java and XUL for my next project.

I want to build the GUI in XUL, but I need certain Java libraries for the business logic.

What options are available for communicating between Java and XUL? I've googled the topic a bit, and there doesn't seem to be a clear best practice for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't exactly lots of options:

- You can put an invisible Java applet into a XUL document somewhere and communicate with that applet from JavaScript.
- You can run a Java application via [nsIProcess](http://web.archive.org/web/20210517025504/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIProcess) and communicate with it via [TCP sockets](http://web.archive.org/web/20210511202709/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIServerSocket).

The first solution seems simpler but it is also more error-prone as some questions here show.